# Joomla: display of articles using RAXO All-mode PRO and JXtended labels

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm currently working on a site that uses the 'RAXO All-mode PRO' module to display a list of articles on the home page, and the 'JXtended labels' component to display pages containing a list of articles associated with given labels. The front-end functionality in both is very similar - get a list of articles and display them.

Ideally, I'd like both lists to display articles in the same format. However, since each component/module has its own way of fetching the data, and its own template, they're currently inconsistent. What's the best way of going about resolving this?

I can envisage a common bit of code (a module? plugin? component?) that deals with the display of a list of articles, and has its own template for that purpose. I guess I'd then need to hack the existing module and component to hand over to this common piece. There's also the question of getting the same set of data - e.g. RAXO All-mode PRO currently gets an article's category; JXtended labels doesn't.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Any idea where I can get a copy of Jxtended Labels install files? I need to migrate a site from 1.5 to 3.x and the jxtended site is not longer active(seems like the whole company is gone under)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of the modules pulling different data sets can only be remedied by hacking the core to get the data that is missing.

Everything else can be accomplished by a simple override. You can modify the module template files then save the new version in JOOMLA/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/MODULE NAME/default.php. You can make the override files match pretty much exactly so the display will be consistent across both modules.

Comment: OK, I'll have to have a careful think about the data issue. Seems like the two options are a) hack the labels component to fetch the additional data b) write my own component/module that performs both these functions, possibly utilising the existing tables. Neither of these seems great, but I'm leaning towards the second. Either way, the template override mechanism looks perfect for my needs, and will go a long way to fixing the problem, even before I deal with the data issue. Thanks.

Comment: If you already have a couple of modules that are similar, rewriting the module and combining the two is not particularly difficult. Modules are fairly easy to put together, especially if you have a good base to modify.

Comment: Right, I'm *probably* going to do that. It's a shame there isn't - apparently - an easier way of integrating modules, because it would be nice to benefit from future updates to either. However, given that raxo all mode 1.5 has never - seemingly - had a single update, I'm probably not going to miss out on much! As a side-note, I'm a bit disappointed about the Joomla! extension community. It seems as if extensions (including these two) are GLP'd but severely lack in open source development - i.e. code repositories, bug trackers, etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: The size of the Joomla dev community is both a blessing and a hindrance. If you use extensions from the larger or more reliable devs you will get regular updates. Akeeba, Phoca, Gavick, Rockettheme, Yootheme, NoNumber and others are very good about releasing regular feature, bug, and security updatses. But for every one of those there are a bunch of other extensions that are not well coded, never updated, or just abandoned. Unfortunately there are many of those extensions that are also very handy. You just have to take the good with the bad.